# CSS sticky footer makes scroll bar unscrollable in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, sticky-footer

I'm using this sticky footer in my website:
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

It is fully working in Firefox, Chrome, IE7, but not IE8. In IE8 the scrollbar appears but doesn't work, and I don't have any other way to move down. I'm using the conditional statement that appears in the web:

```
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Sorry, but I can't post an address, I don't have a server online right now with the web.

Comment: Have you tried bringing your code back to the basics, as described in the article. And does it work then? Their article seems to suggest it works fine in all browsers, so there's probably _something_ different in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alec,

I decided to retry to move the code back to the basics. But this time, I consider that maybe it was related to other CSS I had in my website, bingo!

Finally found the CSS rule that was making the scrollbar unusable. I was using a gradient color for the background of the body:

```
body {
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#52a0d6',  endColorstr='#024f7c');
}
```

Now I'm using an image for the background and the scrollbar is working and the sticky footer is right where it should be.

Comment: If you've solve the problem, mark your answer as "Accepted" so it doesn't show up in the unsolved questions list any more. Oh, and by the way, off-topic, but if you're using gradients, you may want to consier looking into [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) for a more standards-compliant method, and get rid of those ugly `filter` styles.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, but I can't mark my own answer as accepted for 2 days, sorry. I'm using CSS3Pie for some stuff, but not the filters, I will look at it.

Comment: It looks like PIE cannot be used in body: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues#issue/29